# Binary White-listed?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, windows-8

When I try to install on a Win8 64bit using the live CD I get a black screen with the words " Binary Whitelisted". I have searched around but the only thing I found was " add "nomodeset" in grub" [Found it here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2099302) But I am not sure how to do that.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the CD is loading you will a keyboard and white guy in a circle. When you see this, hit a key.

- You'll be prompted to select your language, do so.
- Hit the F6 key to bring up the Other options,
- Use the arrow keys to scroll down to "nomodeset" and hit Enter
- Hit Escape to get back
- Select "Try Ubuntu without Installing" or "Install Ubuntu" and hit Enter.

If it is a "nomodeset" issue, this will fix it.

Also, since this is a Windows 8 machine, disable Secure Boot in UEFI before you attempt an Ubuntu installation. I've also seen references to Secure Boot causing this error message.

Comment: But the CD does'nt load, it just goes form the ASUS ( Laptop brand)  loading screen to a black screen which says Binary Whitelisted. I not sure if I understand when I have to press a key.

Comment: Oh I see. I was under the impression that you were getting the message after the CD started booting. That's really odd. Did disabling secure boot allow you to boot the CD?

Answer (score 0):

The "binary is whitelisted" message comes from the [shim program,](http://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/20303.html) which is shipped standard with recent versions of Ubuntu (and several other distributions). It is not an error message per se. If the computer is hanging after that message is displayed and before anything else is booted, it means that there's a bug in shim or in whatever program it launches (normally GRUB). Disabling Secure Boot *might* fix the problem, but it's more likely that something else is going wrong. You might need to install [another EFI-mode boot loader](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) (which is difficult to do on an installation medium) or install in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode and then either leave it booting that way or convert the computer to boot in EFI mode by installing an EFI-mode boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. In my case, I looked at the boot order on my Asus motherboard, and it was trying to install Ubuntu through UEFI. I changed that to a normal installation, and it worked just fine.

Comment: Probably add this as a comment?